# Query Mongodb docs with the dict field not exists or exists and empty

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Assume there is a some docs:

```
# No 'value'
{
'name': 'T1',
}

# 'value' is a non-empty dict
{
'name': 'T1',
'value': {'a':'A', 'b':'B'}
}

# 'value' is a empty dict
{
'name': 'T1',
'value' : {}
}
```

What I want to query is docs with `value` not exists or `value` exists and is empty. I tried following method and doesn't work:

```
cursor = collection.find({
            'name': {"$exists": 1},
            'value': {"$or": [{"$exists":0}, {"$eq": {}}]}
        })
```

The error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: unknown operator: $or
```

Comment: Because $or should.be top level key, not inside field. See docs; https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

Comment: so how can I achieve what I want, if put it in top level, how to handle other query args?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [`$or` docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) `$or` can be used only as top level key, not inside fields filters. So you need to invert your second condition:

```
collection.find({
    "name": { "$exists": 1 },
    "$or": [ { "value": { "$exists": 0 } }, { "value": { "$eq": {} } } ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Yaroslav is correct but What if you do something like

```
cursor = collection.find({
            'name': {"$exists": 1},
            'value.a': {"$exists":0}
        });
```

Comment: it only match records not exists, doesn't match records with empty dict.

Comment: yeah right, this query is faulty, $or is the correct way